# URL validation with UrlValidator class

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to validate a link, and with searching I've found about the UrlValidator class.
However, it seems to be not working for me. I've chosen a random url to test.

```
String[] schemes = {"http", "https"};
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
if(urlValidator.isValid("http://www.gonwaognwa.com/")){
    System.out.println("valid");
}else{
    System.out.println("invalid");
}
```

The following code prints valid when my browser can't even connect to it. Am I using it wrong?

My import line:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;
```

Comment: The validator is saying your url is syntactically valid, not that it points to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) is only checking for the syntactical correctness of the URL; **not** if you can actually connect to the web server or not. It only makes sure that a given URL conforms to [Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

Comment: Makes sense. Back to research then. Thanks.

Comment: @user2666218 Right below the Up/Down arrows you'll see a check mark. That would work for new users as well. You can also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) if you like. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Yeah nvm that was embarassing. I've had an account before but forgot the details and got too lazy. Thanks for the welcome anyway!